# line breaking in my post excerpt

Tags: wordpress, line-breaks

How can I make a line break in my post excerpt in WordPress? [I try do it by adding '<'br'>' but in vain  , any other solution please ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlTeV.png)

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/excerpt-with-linebreaks/

Comment: @Osama but i don't have these options in my settings

Comment: https://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/how-do-i-create-linebreaks-in-post-excerpts

Comment: I did some research on the internet and I saw all the links but nothing is useful

Comment: If I try it on my local machine, the_excerpt() function outputs the <br> tags without any problem.

Comment: isn't the case with me @user8230352